# Can promise mechanism replace event system in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We all know the event system is very important for every popular JavaScript frameworks, and many famous frameworks provide promise mechanism such as Jquery, DoJo, too.

But AngularJS is special:

1. it provides promise methods.
2. it provides event methods for DOM elements with JqLite and for $scope with $emit/$broadcast. It seems that Angular suggests to use the watch in service.

My question is when a service's data model is:

1. a very huge list so it is hard to watch
2. shared by many other controllers or directives so the promise seems not enough.

So, can I use a the event mechanism to let the service broadcast its data change? Or there is other better solutions.

Comment: Can you describe a more concrete example of when x could replace y.  You're asking a very broad, non-specific question that may be hard for anyone to answer.

Comment: I faced a similar case and as I didn't want to use the greedy angular `$emit`, `$broadcast`, `$on` angular event system, I used a small pub/sub service: https://github.com/glepretre/angular-pubsub ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can promise mechanism replace event system

In general, NO. Promises do per definition only resolve once and do not change their value thereafter. If you want to emit multiple events, you cannot use promises (or only quite impractible).